# Nested If in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've been tasked to correct someones code in VBA. I've never VBA programmed before so this is very basic.

Am I correct in assuming that after the first Then it checks if the next condition is true and thats where it executes the last line?

```
    If data.Cells(i, 3 + 4).Value <> "" Then

    If data.Cells(i, 2 + y).Value <> "" Then
        tilqa = data.Cells(i, 2 + y)
    End If
```

Comment: This doesn't throw some kind of syntax error?

Comment: You can add this line `Option Explicit` to the top of the VBA file, it will help get compilation errors, See [Option Explicit Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement)

Comment: In the VBA IDE you can place the cursor on any keyword and press F1.  This will bring up the MS Help page for that particular keyword.  I

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have a question about the functioning of a code, try to write a small example, like the one below, with `MsgBox()`, showing exactly what is happening. The `1=1` and `2=2` is always evaluated to `True`:

```
Sub TestMe()

    If 1 = 1 Then
        If 2 = 2 Then
            MsgBox "First check here!"
        Else
            MsgBox "This is not checked!"
        End If
        MsgBox "Then check here!"
    End If

End Sub
```

Amd this is how the `If-Else-End` If may function without `Else`:

```
Sub TestMe()

    If 1 = 1 Then
        If 2 = 2 Then
            MsgBox "First check here!"
        End If
        MsgBox "Then check here!"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you write a conditional statement without an Else? Because that's what my code does and I'm not sure what's happening

Comment: @SaimNazir - I have edited, adding the option without `Else`. In general, simply give it a few tries, delete a few lines and experiment with the code. This is the best way to learn what is happenning.